# Find all references in VS Code not working across whole project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, configuration, intellisense, file-extension

I have a JavaScript project opened in VS Code. There is nothing fancy there, all `*.jsx?` are in `src` folder, files bundled by webpack are stored in `dist`, there are couple of dependencies described in `package.json` and installed in `node_modules`.

Let's say I have two files somewhere in `src` folder: `A.jsx` with React component `A` and `B.jsx` with React component `B` which is using component `A`. When I open my project in VS Code, go to `A.jsx` and ask code to `Find All References` of `A` it's showing only one reference in file `A.jsx` (with `PropTypes` declaration). For VS Code to be able to show reference in `B.jsx` I need to open `B.jsx`, then go back to `A.jsx` and only then both references will be shown...

The same scenario works correctly when files are named `A.js` and `B.js`, the problem seems to be with `*.jsx` extenstion.

What I'd like to have is a way to find **all** references in **whole** project without a need to open all files no matter if the file is save as `.jsx` or `.js`. Is there a way to achieve this?

I've already tried `jsconfig.json` with

```
{
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/**/*.jsx"]
}
```

and

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.jsx": "javascriptreact"
},
```

in my `settings.json`

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I finally googled the solution. In order to load `.jsx` files into the project, VS Code needs `jsconfig.json` with such content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

Here is the answer in their repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100251#issuecomment-646239840